# I get an stream.getTracks is not a function error in PeerJS. How do i fix this?

Tags: webrtc, call, peerjs

so I have been using PeerJS to make a p2p chat application and it works when trying to chat, but when i try to call someone with the function below:

```js
function callEm(id){
  call = peer.call(id,
    navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({video: false, audio: true})
    );

  call.on('stream', function(stream) { // B
      window.remoteAudio.srcObject = stream; // C
      window.remoteAudio.autoplay = true; // D
      window.peerStream = stream; //E
      showConnectedContent(); //F    });
  })
  }
```

[image: That Error]

I get an error from PeerJS saying that `e.getTracks is not a function`
`e.getTracks` is a code in the peerJS library: https://unpkg.com/peerjs@1.3.1/dist/peerjs.min.js

I have been trying everything i find on the internet and I still get this error. I hope someone will be able to help me out.

Edit: I tried the cleaner version of the library( https://unpkg.com/peerjs@1.3.1/dist/peerjs.js) and i  get the error
`stream.getTracks() is not a function`
[image: error]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**So I found the solution, the thing is my code was wrong :P**

so I created a function that calls a person with an Id.
earlier it was:

```
function callEm(id){
  console.log(id);
  console.log(navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({video: false, audio: true}));

  call = peer.call(id,
    // window.localStream
    navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({video: false, audio: true})
    );

  call.on('stream', function(stream) { // B
      window.remoteAudio.srcObject = stream; // C
      window.remoteAudio.autoplay = true; // D
      window.peerStream = stream; //E
      showConnectedContent(); //F    });
  })
  }
```

and the issue was that I provided a promise as a MediaStream instead of the actual value. *dumb mistake I know*

so after a friend in discord pointed that to me and helped me change it,
the function became:

```js
function callEm(id){
  navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({video: false, audio: true})
  .then(function(stream) {
        call = peer.call(id, stream);
        call.on('stream', function(stream) { // B
          window.remoteAudio.srcObject = stream; // C
          window.remoteAudio.autoplay = true; // D
          window.peerStream = stream; //E
          showConnectedContent(); //F    });
        })
    })
    .catch(function(err) {
      console.log("error: " + err);
    })
  );
  }
```

and that fixed it. I didn't work out on answering the call yet, but this sent a call without any errors!

I hope someone finds this useful.

Comment: I am having the same problem. I use socket.io and peerJS. Socket.io to broadcast the peerJs ID to everyone in the room. You can reproduce this problem by quickly refreshing on browser. This is also with peerJs version 1.3.1 stable.

Comment: Didn't this answer help? The error was bec I was passing in a promise rather than the outcome. Maybe try doing what I did in the answer. Good luck. :)